# CPPUNIT_ASSERTs cause system to freeze or hang

Tags: c++, testing, assert, freeze, cppunit

Without providing too much context (as I have seen this issue in many different unit tests) can anyone explain to me why a failing CPPUNIT_ASSERT call will sometimes cause the program to freeze/hang?

For example, I will often use a test program wherein I will see the call...

```
CPPUNIT_ASSERT(condition);
```

This call of course will ideally do nothing if `condition` evaluates to true, or incite a crash and print a statement indicating that a failure occurred at this assert. My problem is that sometimes, these asserts will cause the program to hang when `condition` evaluates to a false.

I have seen numerous functioning tests wherein fails will behave appropriately, but now and then tests I use end up having this issue. This becomes obnoxious as it requires me to debug code just to figure out a test is failing when it should. Has anyone else seen this issue or can anyone provide incite as to why this might be occurring?

Comment: You most likely need to debug this. As a starting point CPPUNIT_ASSERT will throw an exception which will normally be caught by the cppunit test framework and mark that specific test.

Comment: One idea that might explain the problem is that your tests are not completely independent and you have resources that cause the next test to hang. Ideally all tests are completely independent and are not affected by other tests. I have personally never seen cppunit hang without an underlying problem in the code that I test.